# How to make reactstrap modal with dynamic content resizable and draggable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, reactstrap, resizable

I want to make the reactstrap modal with dynamic content from another component resizable and draggable.

My code:

```
    <Draggable>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Add/Edit</ModalHeader>
        {modal ?
          <ModalBody>
            {this.props.dynamicComponent}
          </ModalBody> : ''}
      </Modal>
    </Draggable>
```

I've achieved the draggable by using [`react-draggable`](https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable) but I have a problem with the resizable. I have used [`react-resizable`](https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable) and [`re-resizable`](https://github.com/bokuweb/re-resizable) but if the `<Resizable>` tag before `<Draggable>` they both create space even before the modal has been opened and after opening the Resizable is not working.

I have put the `<Resizable>` tag after `<Draggable>`, the Resizable is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the complete answer, so I decided to remove the Draggable and just add Resizable to the Modal, so I added this CSS code to the modal:

```
.modal-content{
border: 2px solid;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;}
```